# How to update apt-get when error "could not resolve 'us.archive.ubuntu.com'" comes up in ubuntu linux?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, updates, apt-get

Using Linux 3.2.0-32-generic Ubuntu x86_64 when I tried to update using "apt-get update" I received several error messages for many lines of requests to the us ubuntu archives.  It read "could not resolve 'us.archive.ubuntu.com'".  What can I do?

Answer (score 4):

By editing /etc/resolv.conf to remove nameservers and replace with my preferred name servers I was able to connect to the repositories and update using the "apt-get update" command.  An example entry that would work is "nameserver    8.8.8.8", which uses the google name servers.  After saving the file all processes worked without throwing an error.